# ASP.Net - Save some info in the Session within a custom MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, session, membership-provider

I want to save some info in the **Session** when the users successfully logins with my custom **MembershipProvider**, but I have no access to the Session in the provider's `ValidateUser` method.

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    /* Override other methods and properties here */

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        /* do something to validate the username and password 
         * and set the validUser variable */
        if (validUser)
        {
            /* want to store some info in the Session here, but I can't access
             * it here, because this is not a Page */
        }
        return validUser;                
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HttpContext.Current.Session
You need to reference System.Web first. This will get the Session on which the current thread is running. 

Example:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserWhatevetProperty"] = validUser.WhateverProperty;
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually found it while waiting for an answer. The following link gave the answer and also answer me other question: how to destroy the session when logging out with the asp.net loging controls. http://forums.asp.net/t/1131138.aspx